# How do i calculate the inference time of a NN on cpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

how can I find/calculate the inference time of a single image in a Tensorflow CNN?

Answer (score 0):

see code below

```
import time
start_time= time.time() # set the time at which inference started
model.predict (etc
stop_time=time.time()
duration =stop_time - start_time
hours = duration // 3600
minutes = (duration - (hours * 3600)) // 60
seconds = duration - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))
msg = f'training elapsed time was {str(hours)} hours, {minutes:4.1f} minutes, 
       {seconds:4.2f} seconds)'
print (msg, flush=True) # print out inferenceduration time
```